# Cause all processes running under OpenMPI to dump core

Tags: linux, openmpi

I'm running a distributed process under OpenMPI on linux.

When one process dies, mpirun will detect this and kill the other processes. But even though I get a core from the process which died, I don't get a core from the processes killed by OpenMPI.

Why am I not getting these other corefiles? How can I get these corefiles?

Answer (score 0):

The other processes are just killed by Open MPI. They didn't segfault themselves. From an MPI perspective, their execution was erroneous, but from a C perspective, it was fine. As such, there's no reason for them to have dumped core.

Comment: OK, fair enough...so how do I change this behavior and get a corefile?

Comment: You'd have to do some mucking inside Open MPI itself which will be pretty nasty and I have no idea where to tell you to start. The short answer is: you don't. Anyway, there's nothing wrong with their executions. The only process from which you need a core file is the one that actually did something wrong.

Comment: How do you know that's the only process I need the core file from? Maybe the reason process A did something wrong is because process B gave it bogus data. Please don't just tell me that I don't need the thing that I need.

Answer (score 0):

OMPI's `mpiexec` kills the remaining ranks by first sending them `SIGTERM` and then `SIGKILL` (should any of them survive `SIGTERM`). None of those signals results in core being dumped. You could probably install a signal handler for `SIGTERM` that calls `abort(3)` in order to force core dumps on kill.

Here is some sample code that works with Open MPI 1.6.5:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void term_handler (int sig) {
    // Restore the default SIGABRT disposition
    signal(SIGABRT, SIG_DFL);
    // Abort (dumps core)
    abort();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Override the SIGTERM handler AFTER the call to MPI_Init
    signal(SIGTERM, term_handler);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // Cause division-by-zero exception in rank 0
    rank = 1 / rank;
    // Make other ranks wait for rank 0
    MPI_Bcast(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Open MPI's `MPI_Init` installs special handlers for some known signals that either print useful debug information or generate backtrace files (`.btr`). That's why the `SIGTERM` handler has to be installed **after** the call to `MPI_Init` and the default action of `SIGABRT` (used by `abort(3)`) has to be restored before calling `abort()`.

Note that the signal handler will appear at the top of the call stack in the core file:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003bfd232925 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003bfd234105 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000400dac in term_handler (sig=15) at test.c:8
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0x00007fbac7ad0bc7 in mca_btl_sm_component_progress () from /path/libmpi.so.1
#5  0x00007fbac7c9fca7 in opal_progress () from /path/libmpi.so.1
...
```

I would rather recommend that you should use a parallel debugger such as TotalView or DDT, if you have one at your disposal.